# Error message for processing big data

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I have a problem when i process files in php. When processing small files, it can be seen the output. But, when large files it shows the warning like this :

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1068498944) (tried to allocate 133955584 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ujian_online\application\views\data_soal\view_proses.php on line 644

we can see the code like this :

```
    <?php
                                                       $no_urut = 0;
                                                        //print_r($array_query_simantic_reletedness);
                                                        foreach ($val_simantic_reletedness as $doc_simantic_word) {
                                                            foreach ($array_query_simantic_reletedness as $text_simantic_current_key => $text_simantic_current_val) {
                                                                //get fix val
                                                                $status = 0;
                                                                $spe = 0;
                                                                $sr = 0;
                                                                if ($text_simantic_current_key == $doc_simantic_word) {
                                                                    $status++;
                                                                    $spe = 1;
                                                                }
                                                                $where_get_kamus = array('kata' => $text_simantic_current_key);
                                                                $get_kamus = $this->master->find_data($where_get_kamus, 'tb_kamus')->row_array();
                                                                // print_r($get_kamus);
                                                                //split kamus by ';'
                                                                $kamus_synonim = explode(';', $get_kamus['synonim']);
                                                                //split kata by '.'

                                                                foreach ($kamus_synonim as $key_word_split => $val_word_split) {
                                                                    $kata_current_kamus = explode(';', $val_word_split);
                                                                    //print_r($kata_current_kamus);
                                                                    foreach ($kata_current_kamus as $key_current_word_doc => $val_current_word_doc) {
                                                                        //split by doc 
                                                                        $word_split_doc = explode('.', $val_current_word_doc);
                                                                        if (empty($word_split_doc[0])) {
                                                                            continue;
                                                                        }
                                                                        if (isset($word_split_doc[1])) {
                                                                            $word_split_slash = explode('|', $word_split_doc[1]);
                                                                        }
                                                                        // print_r($word_split_slash);
                                                                        // ---- foreach for checking ---
                                                                        foreach ($word_split_slash as $val_current_word_check) {
                                                                            //print_r($val_current_word_check);
                                                                            $val_current_word_check = str_replace(' ', '', $val_current_word_check);
                                                                            $val_current_word_check = str_replace("\r", '', $val_current_word_check);
                                                                            $val_current_word_check = str_replace("\t", '', $val_current_word_check);
                                                                            $val_current_word_check = str_replace("\n", '', $val_current_word_check);
                                                                            // print_r($val_current_word_check);
                                                                            if ($doc_simantic_word == strtolower($val_current_word_check)) {
                                                                                $status++;
                                                                                // penentuan dmax
                                                                                $where_get_spe_check = array('kata' => $doc_simantic_word);
                                                                                $get_word_spe = $this->master->find_data($where_get_spe_check, 'tb_kamus')->row_array();
                                                                                if ($get_kamus['dmax'] > $get_word_spe['dmax']) {
                                                                                    $dmax_spe = $get_kamus['dmax'];
                                                                                } else {
                                                                                    $dmax_spe = $get_word_spe['dmax'];
                                                                                }
                                                                                //count spe
                                                                                $spe = $get_kamus['dmax'] / $dmax_spe;
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                        //---- end foreach for checking ----------------
                                                                        //echo '<br>';
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                $no_urut++;
                                                                if ($status > 0) {
                                                                    $val_view = 1;
                                                                } else {
                                                                    $val_view = 0;
                                                                    $spe = 0;
                                                                }
                                                                $sr = $spe * $val_view;

                                                                echo "
                                              <tr>
                                                  <td>$no_urut</td> 
                                                  <td>$text_simantic_current_key " . '=' . " $doc_simantic_word</td>
                                                  <td>$val_view</td>
                                                  <td>$spe</td>
                                                  <td>$sr</td>
                                              </tr>

                                              ";
                                                //  echo '||';echo $no_urut;echo '|'; echo $text_simantic_current_key ; echo '=' ;echo $doc_simantic_word;echo '|'; echo $val_view;echo '|'; echo $spe;echo '|'; echo $sr;
                                                            }
                                                        }//end simantic word doc
                                                        ?>




and i give the highlight for line 644 is 

    > echo "
                                                  <tr>
                                                      <td>$no_urut</td> 
                                                      <td>$text_simantic_current_key " . '=' . " $doc_simantic_word</td>
                                                      <td>$val_view</td>
                                                      <td>$spe</td>
                                                      <td>$sr</td>
                                                  </tr>
       >                                           ";

But when i check my code in https://phpcodechecker.com/
i have the different notice like this :

    Error: There is 1 more opening parenthesis '(' found
    This count is unaware if parenthesis are inside of a string

and we can see the code :



    $get_data_tema = $this->master->find_data(array('id_tema'=>$key_val_final),'tb_tema')->row_array();
                                                 echo 'nama tema " <b>'.$get_data_tema['nama'].'</b>"';
                                            }
                                            $array_post_input = array('text_soal'=> $data_post['text_soal'],
                                                                    'a' =>$data_post['a'],
                                                                    'b' =>$data_post['b'],
                                                                    'c' =>$data_post['c'],
                                                                    'd' =>$data_post['d'],
                                                                    'e' =>$data_post['e'],
                                                                    'answer' =>$data_post['answer'],
                                                                    'guru_id'=> $this->session->userdata('id_current'),
                                                                    'tema_id'=>0,
                                                                    'mapel_id' =>$data_post['mapel_id'],
                                                                    'gbrsoal' =>$data_post['gbrsoal'],'label_id'=>0,
                                                                        );
                                            $this->master->insert_data('tb_soal',$array_post_input);
```

I am using xampp version v3.2.2 and windows 8.1, RAM 8 GB with 6,94 useable, PHP version 5.6.15 with codeigniter framework and i have set in memory limit inside php.ini 51200000000000 M. So, what should i do to fix my problem? Which line must be i repair it? Thanks.

Comment: You actually have "51200000000000M" ?  That's way more than installed RAM.  8GB is about 8000MB.

Comment: If you don't want to use a debugger like [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) and see what is actually happening try to comment some lines till you know which lines are exhausting the memory, normally the variables assignment inside those 5 nested loops

Comment: Please sort out the code in your question. It's pretty unreadable. You should also narrow the issue down and not just post a bunch of code and let us figure out where your issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the **first problem**: With a large amount of data, the printing process can be very resource expensive. So, save the printable parts into an array and print them once, after all *foreach* iterations are finished. Note: look for `$results` in my code.

```
<?php

$results = [];
$no_urut = 0;

foreach ($val_simantic_reletedness as $doc_simantic_word) {
    foreach ($array_query_simantic_reletedness as $text_simantic_current_key => $text_simantic_current_val) {

        //...

        $sr = $spe * $val_view;

        $results[] = "<tr>
                        <td>$no_urut</td> 
                        <td>$text_simantic_current_key " . '=' . " $doc_simantic_word</td>
                        <td>$val_view</td>
                        <td>$spe</td>
                        <td>$sr</td>
                    </tr>";
    }
}

echo implode('', $results);
```

Solution for the **second problem** (if I understood it correctly): remove the "}" character which appears right after the line

```
echo 'nama tema " <b>' . $get_data_tema['nama'] . '</b>"';
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try to insert **ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');** in php file